# Timer delegate call says "The memory could not be read"

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

So here's the thing i  have a function and a timer that has an interval of 10ms.

```
void process()
{
    //some heavy processing logic here
}
```

Now what i'm doing is that i have added this function to the timer.tick delegeate

```
timer1.tick += process;
```

When I run my program I'm getting exception that says

> Multiple threads started to execute the same block and 'The instruction at some address referenced to another address.The memory could not be read'

But when I increase the interval time to 500ms, this exception is thrown after some time.
I am kind of new to c#, Is there any other efficient way of doing this without facing such an error.

Comment: sounds like you have multiple threads trying to access a common resource that isn't thread-safe.  What are you doing inside of the "heavy processing", are you kicking off new threads?

Comment: NO it's just a simple function that is extracting frames from a video file @DylanSmith

Comment: @Harry47 try replacing the process body with some other dummy processing to check if it is timer or the video processing which is causing the issue. Also paste the `StackTrace` if possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i realized that in this function i had some variables that were being used by the program to run correctly , so when this function was being accessed many a times by different threads at the same time , it malfunctioned. 
So i prevented this by using locks

```
void process()
{
   lock(frameExtractor) // frame extractor is the variable where frames are stored
   //  then do some heavy processing 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You starting process every timer tick, so after a while your pc will really slow down. It is because you do not control thread numbers.Moreover I assume that they are using same resources, because you do not pass any arguments. This resources are probably not thread safe and this causes an exception

Comment: Here is the main function 
private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
and i am not creating any threads

Comment: But you do not wait until your function finish. So many procesing is done parallel even if it is in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

timers tick trigger after interval finish.  your function in use by multiple ruinning Context . change timer interval as long as max run of your Process method and  change to this ( disable timer in start function and enable after that ):

```
void process()
{
timer1.Enabled=false;
//some heavy processing
timer1.Enabled=true;
}
```

otherwise you must use semaphores.